# What can be concluded about coefficients?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I run multiple variable regression and got the following result. What can i conclude regarding the significance of coefficients? And why?

Thanks

```
SUMMARY OUTPUT                      



ANOVA                                   
            Coefficients    t Stat   P-value    
Intercept   0.00191         6.27072  0.00000    
RPt         0.98782         56.85940 0.00000    
SMB         0.87223         31.19128 0.00000    
HML         0.68983         31.76355 0.00000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

The simple answer to your question is that all the coefficients are highly significant because they all have very low p values (not literally 0 despite the output, but < .00001).

However, be aware that statistical significance does not equal practical importance.

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter. So the intercept is statistically different from zero which i am not expecting.

Comment: What was your sample size? What is your dependent variable? How is it measured? 0.0019 is pretty small, but it depends on how it's measured.

Comment: i'm testing Fama & French three factor model on a stock exchange in Vietnam. The model is as follow: ERPt = αP + RPtβ1t + (SMB)β2t + (HML)β3t + еt. ERPt is daily excess return of an stock portfolio. Number of observations: 937. The model is expected to be good if intercept is not significant and βs are significant.

Comment: Your comment got cut off. To make a paragraph in a comment hit <shift><enter>. Just <enter> will submit your comment.

Comment: i'm testing Fama & French three factor model on a stock exchange in Vietnam. The model is as follow:
ERPt = αP + RPtβ1t + (SMB)β2t + (HML)β3t + еt.
ERPt is daily excess return of an stock portfolio. Number of observations: 937. The model is expected to be good if intercept is not significant and βs are significant.

Comment: Judging a model by whether coefs. are significant doesn't seem sensible; particularly not the intercept. Is an ERPt of 0.0019 of any importance?

Comment: ERPt of 0.0019 (0.19%) seems to be important i think? The mean of ERPt is 0.3%.

Comment: You would know better than I whether it's important. But certainly 0.19 is a large component of 0.3